# Change input 'min' attribute in options-reading.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to change the 'min' attribute of posts_per_page input to '2' from my functions.php file.

**options-reading.php**

```
<input name="posts_per_page" type="number" step="1" min="1" id="posts_per_page" value="<?php form_option( 'posts_per_page' ); ?>" class="small-text" /> <?php _e( 'posts' ); ?>
```

This is what I have but it doesn't work.

**functions.php**

```
function my_enqueue($hook) {

    if ( 'options-reading.php' != $hook ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-javascript', get_template_directory_uri() 
    .'/assets/js/custom.js', '20151215', true );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue');
```

**custom.js**

```
jQuery("#posts_per_page").attr({
   "min" : 2
});
```

P.S: I added the javascript code at the end of options-reading.php and works good, so looks like the problem is not javascript related.

Comment: Try `jQuery("#posts_per_page").attr("min", 2);`

Comment: The same, it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the file named `custom.php` or `custom.js`?

Comment: Sorry, it's custom.js, already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this using `JS`?

```
var input = document.getElementById("posts_per_page");
    input.setAttribute("min", 2);
```

Comment: Yes I tried and throw an error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null)

Comment: In the file custom.js

Comment: Try putting the code in options-reading.php script before the end of the body

Comment: Don't forget to put js inside script tag

Comment: I updated my question, and yes, works good at the end of options-reading.php but I need to change the attribute from my functions.php file.

Comment: Then paste the code inside your functions.php inside script tag and link both files property